# Add column to dataframe with the order parameter of a groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1), 3343],
        [datetime(2020, 1, 1), 3443],
        [datetime(2020, 2, 1), 5431],
        [datetime(2020, 2, 1), 4443],
        [datetime(2020, 2, 1), 7999],
    ],
    columns=["A", "B"],
)
```

[image]

I want to add a new column to the dataframe, that shows the order position for each column A, considering the ordering parameter the column B.
Thus, the result of the previous dataframe would be:

[image]

The goal is to do it in an efficient way, not using for loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `rank`.

```
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

Or as @АлексейР suggested, first sort the DataFrame by 'B' and then use `groupby` + `cumcount`.

```
df = df.sort_values(['A', 'B'])
df['new_column'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount() + 1
```

Comment: `df = df.sort_values(['A', 'B']).assign(newcolumn=lambda x: x.A.groupby(x['A']).cumcount() + 1)`?

Comment: @АлексейР good one too, I thought of that too! It's only required to sort by 'B', but I guess that way is more clear